# Downloading text version of website

Tags: http, text

How can I download the text version of a website? I need to do that using http raw protocol, e.g. telnet. However, I have no idea. Any hint?

Comment: Are you supposed to write a *program* that does the downloading? Otherwise I think this question should be on [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/). Also, reading about the [HyperText Transfer Protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol) might give you some hints.

Comment: No, I don't have to write a program. Thanks for a hint.

Comment: Telnet is not "http raw".  HTTP is always already "raw" in that it's just as direct content dump without flow-control or packetization or interaction.  It's also already "text".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a command line tool such as curl or wget.

e.g. to save the google homepage to the file google.html:

```
curl -L google.com > google.html
```

or

```
wget google.com > google.html
```

Comment: I have managed to use curl as you told me but I think the task is not about that. I think the result should be we can do here: http://www.textise.net/
but I need to use telnet or something like that.